# Javascript fix duplicated output

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

This is my code, everything is working good only when i try to output an array, i get the whole array again and again with the new value each time. But i actually want is to output the whole array as a block below eachother and each time i click on check i get the new value in the array and printed in the left Woorden Geprobeerd list With no duplicated value. Does someone know how i can fix this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl"> 

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Lingo spel</title>
 <meta name="Lingo" content="Making an lingo project for school">
<meta name="Author" content="Ronald Julian Dewindt">
<meta name="Made Date" content="18-11-2015">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Montserrat|Raleway|Poiret+One|Indie+Flower|Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--<div class="col-xs-12">
                    <img src="lingo_logo.jpg">
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label>Typ een eu land hier in:</label>

                <input class="form-control input" type="text" id="woord">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="lingo()">Check</button>
                        <p style="padding-left:10px; display:inline-block;"><b>punten:</b></p><p style="display:inline-block;" id="punten">0</p>
                        <p style="padding-left:20px; display:inline-block;"><b>Kansen:</b></p><p style="display:inline-block;" id="kans">30</p>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <h4>Woorden Geprobeerd</h4>
                    <p class="try" id="try"></p> 
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-3">
                    <h4>Correcte woord</h4>
                    <p class="word" id="hiddenWord"></p>
                </div>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                            var euLanden = new Array('Nederland','Belgie','Bulgarije','Cyprus','Denemarken','Duitsland','Estland','Finland','Frankrijk','Griekeland','Ierland','Italie','Luxemburg','Malta','Oostenrijk','Polen','Spanje','Zweden','Hongarije','Kroatie','Letland','Litouwen','Portugal','Roemenie','Slovenie','Tsjechie');
                var random =   euLanden[Math.floor(Math.random() * euLanden.length)]; 
                var woordenTry=  new Array();
                var tryOutput = "";
                var punten=    0;
                var kans=      30;              document.getElementById("hiddenWord").innerHTML="?".repeat(random.length);
                function lingo(countryName, textInput)
                { 
                    textInput = document.getElementById("woord").value;
                    textInput = textInput.toLowerCase(); 
                    countryName = random.toLowerCase();
                    var output = "";
                    for(var i=0; i< countryName.length; i++)
                    { 
                        if(textInput.indexOf(countryName[i])!== -1)
                            {
                                output += countryName[i];
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                output += "?";
                            }
                    }
                    woordenTry.push(output);

                    for(w=0; w<woordenTry.length; w++)
                        {      
                                document.getElementById("hiddenWord").innerHTML=output;
                                tryOutput+= woordenTry[w] + "<br>";
                                document.getElementById("try").innerHTML=tryOutput;
                        }
                    if(textInput != countryName)
                        {
                            kans--;
                        }
                    if(kans == 0)
                        {
                            alert("U heeft verloren, Probeer opnieuw");
                            location.reload();

                        }
                    if(textInput === countryName)
                        {
                    random = euLanden[Math.floor(Math.random() * euLanden.length)];
                    random.length
                    alert("Je hebt het woord gevonden");
                            punten++;
                    alert("Zoek het nieuw woord op!");
                                 document.getElementById("hiddenWord").innerHTML="?".repeat(countryName.length);        
                        }
                    document.getElementById("punten").innerHTML=punten;
                    document.getElementById("kans").innerHTML=kans;
                }
                </script>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please learn how to produce a "small, self contained test case" that demonstrates your problem.  Chances are when you do that you'll actually find the problem.

Comment: It's also a good idea to write code in English so that when you want to ask for help, people can understand the code :)

Comment: You are always appending to `woordenTry` and `tryOutput`. I'm not clear over exactly what you want either of those to be, or why you need both, but at least one of them should probably be reset at each attempt.